# Как разбить строку на слова C++ (Arduino)

Tags: c++, массивы, arduino, split

На вход мы должны дать **"test=qwerty"** разделить нужно по = 
Например **split("test=qwerty","=")** на выходе должны получить массив **["test","qwerty"]**

В C++ скажу честно я не силен (откровенно ламер). стоит задача создать веб морду для ардуино для управления умным домом. esp8266 я поднял, сделал ответ на GET (вкл/выкл) светодиода у 13 pin`а, теперь сделал форму для выбора типа подключения при нажатии кнопки отправить на ардуинку приходит GET запрос "GET /?contents=sc HTTP 1.1" я смог убрать GET /? и HTTP 1.1 и теперь мне нужно сделать действия на атрибуты.

```
String split ( String text, char del ) {
  char arr[99];
  int count = 0;
  char step_text = "";
  for ( int i=0; i<text.length(); i++ ) {

    step_text += (char)text[i];
    if ( text[i] == del ) {
      arr[count] = step_text;
      count++;
      step_text = "";
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Нужно доработать функцию выше или ткнуть на ошибки.
Я прогуглил часа 3 не нашел ничего нужного поэтом написал сюда )

Comment: А чем вам `strtok` не устраивает? Если реально чем-то не устраивает, используйте смещения и `std::copy`. Либо записывать каждый символ по очереди, до конца и начала пробела, если попался пробел, начинается сразу после новое слово.

Comment: я пробовал strstok использовать, не получилось у меня, нашел даже готовую функцию но arduino IDE ругалась на strtok(null,del)

Comment: Arduino не то чтобы очень приспособлен для обработки строк в стиле PHP. Слишком мало ОЗУ, чтобы создавать массив из объектов типа String. Придумайте алгоритм без копирования строк. Придумайте вообще без строк.

Comment: Пишите на чистом Си (писанины будет немного больше, а проблем намного меньше)

Comment: у меня Arduino Mega я думаю в ней достаточно озу для обработки строк )

Answer (score -1):

Можно вот так попробовать. Если нужно вернуть массив из двух частей.

```
String* split ( String text, char del ) {
  char arr[2];
  int count = 0;
  for ( int i=0; i<text.length(); i++ ) {

    if(oneLine.charAt(i) == del) 
     { 
      sa[0] = oneLine.substring(0, i); 
      sa[1] = oneLine.substring(i+1, text.length()-1); 
     }
   }
  return arr;
}
```

Если строка содержит больше двух значение с разделителями, то рассмотрим функцию, которая возвращает часть с номером index:

```
String getPart(String text, char del, int index)
{
  int found = 0;
  int sInd[] = {0, -1};
  int mInd = text.length()-1;

  for(int i=0; i<=mInd && found<=index; i++){
    if(text.charAt(i)==del || i==mInd){
        found++;
        sInd[0] = sInd[1]+1;
        sInd[1] = (i == mInd) ? i+1 : i;
    }
  }

  return found>index ? text.substring(sInd[0], sInd[1]) : "";
}
```

Пример

```
String text = "p1=p2=p3";
String part2 = getPart(text, '=', 1);
Serial.println(part2); // p2
```

Comment: в функции getPart присутствует переменная data, что это ? (в if) 
Как я понял data = text, а вот ардуино ругается на 'strIndex' was not declared in this scope

Comment: была опечатка исправил

Comment: `char arr[2]` - это массив из двух символов. А функция возвращает указатель на String. Это вообще не скомпилируется.